# How to get Normal(Gauss) distribution from unifrom distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab, uniform-distribution

I need to use rand(uniform distribution) function in matlab to generate a gaussian/normal distribution. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: See also here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132556/advantages-of-box-muller-over-inverse-cdf-method-for-simulating-normal-distribut